# Как синхронизировать пользователей?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html5

Когда заходит первый пользователь ему присваивается рандомный `id` он записывается в базу данных, пользователь  может нажимать на кнопку  <kbd>менять значение</kbd>. Теперь когда заходит второй пользователь он нажимает <kbd>изменить значение</kbd>, он меняет своё значение, допустим, на 50 и меняет значение первого пользователя на 50. Но первому пользователю выходит строка, что другой пользователь изменил его значение. На первом скриншоте показывается как должно выглядеть окно у первого пользователя.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сейчас выглядит окно у первого пользователя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сейчас выглядит окно у второго пользователя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
База данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 50; // id пользователя равняется рандомному целому числу

function funcBefore() { // функция пока загружается обычно это гифка загрузки
  $("#information").text("Ожидание данных...") // пока идёт выходить такое сообщение 
}

function funcSuccess(data) {} // ответ которые мы получили с php

$.ajax({ // сам метод ajax
  url: "chek.php", // куда отправлять данные 
  type: "POST", // метод отправки данных 
  data: ({
    number: id
  }), // отправляем id в базу данных 
  dataType: "html", // тип отправки сообщения
  beforeSend: funcBefore, // пока документ загружается эта фун выполняется
  success: function(data) {
    if (data == "00000") {

    } else {

    }
  }
});

var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 50; // изменения которые производятся равны целому числу 

function q9() { // добавляет кнопки 
  btn5 = document.createElement('BUTTON'); // создание кнопки 
  btn5.textContent = 'изменить значение'; // текст
  btn5.id = 'cmd5'; // её id может пригодится
  document.body.appendChild(btn5); // нужно чтобы добавилась кнопка 
  btn5.onclick = function() { // функция когда кликаем по ней
    q7(a); // отправка этой переменной в функцию 
  }
}

q9(); // вызов фун с кнопкой 

btn4 = document.createElement('getElementById'); // созадние шкалы
btn4.id = 'cmd4'; // id
document.body.appendChild(btn4); // нужно для добавления

var h = 1000; // начальное значие 
var z; //  то что отнимаем 

document.getElementById('cmd4').innerHTML = 'по умолчанию ' + h; // вывод начального значения 

function q7(z) { // отнимаем текущее здоровье 
  h = h + z; // прибавление переменной для изменения 
  elem = document.getElementById('cmd4');
  elem.innerHTML = '<div> id-пользователя' + " " + id + " " + "изменил значение на " + " " + z + " " + "текущее значение" + " " + h + '</div>' + elem.innerHTML; //вывод всей информации
  allAnswers = elem.getElementsByTagName('div');
  if (allAnswers.length > 6) { // число - это лимит количества сообщений
    elem.removeChild(allAnswers[20]); // когда больше 20 удаляем 
  }
}
```

```css
#cmd4 {
  position: absolute;
  /* выводятся все изменённые значения */
  top: 0px;
  /* вверх низ */
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- полотно где отображается код -->
<canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="300"></canvas>
```

Файл PHP:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mybase3"); // подключение к базе данных
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8' "); // кодировка
$k = $_POST['number']; // получаем id

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `qwe3` (`id`) VALUES ('$k')"); // записываем id пользователя в базу данных
$mysqli->close(); // закрытие бд
?>
```

Comment: Почему у Вас `canvas` в теге `head`?

Comment: исправил,странно но canvas в head правильно работал поэтому и не обратил внимание

Comment: Почему у Вас `canvas` в теге `script`?

Comment: да да  в body должен быть

Comment: вы лучше скажите понятно описал вопрос? если ,что я исправлю

Comment: Вот почему у вас есть ajax на отправку данных, но нет на получение? Причём повторяющееся

Comment: Знаю,нужно делать на получение,но логику не смог построить как правильно получать.